# Ordenar resultados Mysql utilizando duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, classificação, count

é o seguinte, eu tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada topicos e outra comentarios(que possui uma chave estrangeira da tabela topicos), eu queria listar os tópicos ordenando eles pela quantidade de comentários de cada um. Quebrei a cabeça e não consegui fazer, agradeço a ajuda desde já. Valeu!

Comment: Coloca sua query aí pra gente te ajudar

Comment: As respostas funcionaram perfeitamente! Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Fiz uma pequena alteração... para retornar 0 (zero) caso não tenha nenhum comentário. Agora está melhor. Me fala se precisar melhorar algo mais na consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o `COUNT` com o `GROUP BY`.

Não conheço sua estrutura, mas é isso que você tem que fazer.

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(COUNT(COMENTARIOS.ID), 0) AS QUANTIDADE_COMENTARIOS
FROM
    COMENTARIOS
GROUP BY
    ID_TOPICO
ORDER BY
    QUANTIDADE_COMENTARIOS
```

Answer (score 4):

Segue um exemplo de consulta:

```
SELECT 
    t.NOME_TOPICO
    , count(c.id) qtd_comentarios

FROM TABELA_TOPICOS as t
left join TABELA_COMENTARIOS as c on c.fk_uf = t.id

group by t.id

order by count(t.id) desc
```